# Is there a flag or member variable that I can access to indicated odometry lost in RTAB-Map?

Tags: rtabmap, rtabmap-ros, ros-noetic, rtabmap-odometry

Is there a flag/service/variable that I can access programmatically which will indicate rtabmap odometry lost? I am attempting to use rgbd_odometry (RTAB-Map 0.21) in ROS-Noetic, and requires stopping the movement of a robot arm when odometry is lost. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The pose in the odometry topic will be invalid (quaternion with all 0s). Reference: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/d974c9a72c2234f61e51624c7066588275666946/rtabmap_odom/src/OdometryROS.cpp#L811-L835